# How to allow rotated div to overflow table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table cell with a div that has a height of 3px and a width more than the cell width. I am using `transform: rotate` and using the div to represent a rotated line.

Even though I am using `table-layout:fixed`, the div stretches the table cell horizontally. I want it to overlay the table if it does not fit in the cell.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20px;">
      <div style="width: 100px;
                  height: 3px;
                  background: #000;
                  transform: rotate(20deg);"></div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100px;">Why am I pushed away?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. I am using the right vendor prefixes for rotation in the actual code

Comment: Can you add this to jsFiddle ?

Comment: I think if you set the z-index of the div to something other than zero, it's shouldn't resize the table.

Comment: @IsaacFife that didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: is there any reason you aren't using a border for a horizontal line?

Comment: will text overflow:ellipsis not help

Comment: Tried and it didn't. The point is that here it is a `div` that overlaps not some text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `position:absolute` to the div might be what you're looking for?

**Accepted Answer:**
On another note, something I didn't catch right away, in order to use table-layout:fixed you need to specify a width on the table itself. In your case i think you would want it at 120px and that would accomplish what you need.

Comment: I want it to be positioned relatively in the cell, but still overlap the table and have the cell size not change with the size of the `div`.

Comment: Okay.  On another note, something I didn't catch right away, in order to use table-layout:fixed you need to specify a width on the table itself.  In your case i think you would want it at 120px and that would accomplish what you need.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I'm accepting your answer for this comment, so it would be good if you edited this remark in or pointed to it so it doesn't confuse further readers of the question.